# Jupyter Notebook Couldn't find program: 'sh' on windows

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use the cell magic %%sh in a notebook, and it returns the following error:

```
Ln [1]:
%%sh
ls

> Couldn't find program: 'sh'
```

When I try the exact same command when I open jupyter notebook from another python virtualenv, it works.
I am running on Windows.

I tried to compare the installed modules within the virtualenvs, but I didn't find what is causing it.

Any idea how to solve it or what can I check?

Answer (score 0):

On windows, use **cmd** instead of **sh**. Also, use **dir** instead of **ls**.

```
%%cmd
dir
```